# Passenger cannot load rbenv managed versions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler, rbenv

A server has two users. `deploy` has sudo privileges, `guest` does not. 
guest has an application that is migrating ruby versions (from 2.3.4 to 2.4.5).

Initially, after guest installs version 2.4.5 passenger cannot start because it does not find this version of ruby. `deploy` had to install it.  However, hte next phase of starting up the server fails to load the application, while at the same time confirming that it is seeking the version of ruby within the `deploy` user's directories

```
Error: The application encountered the following error: cannot load such file -- bundler/setup (LoadError)
/home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.4.5/lib/ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
/home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.4.5/lib/ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:363:in `activate_gem'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:221:in `block in run_load_path_setup_code'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:527:in `running_bundler'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:220:in `run_load_path_setup_code'
/usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-loader.rb:86:in `load_app'
/usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-loader.rb:116:in `block in <module:App>'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:380:in `run_block_and_record_step_progress'
/usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-loader.rb:115:in `<module:App>'
/usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-loader.rb:28:in `<module:PhusionPassenger>'
/usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-loader.rb:27:in `<main>'
```

`passenger-config --ruby-command` seems to be looking for the proper directory,

```
passenger-config was invoked through the following Ruby interpreter:
  Command: /home/guest/.rbenv/versions/2.4.5/bin/ruby
  Version: ruby 2.4.5p335 (2018-10-18 revision 65137) [x86_64-linux]
```

However,

```
rbenv exec gem environment gemdir
```

returns

```
/home/guest/.rbenv/versions/2.3.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0
```

How can this be fixed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here relates to different users and ruby versions invoked.

```
passenger-config --ruby-command
```

returns the interesting passage, in this case:

```
 To use in Nginx : passenger_ruby /home/guest/.rbenv/versions/2.4.5/bin/ruby
```

while the `nginx/sites-enabled/relevant_application` file does not need to have that invoked for a single user, this command becomes necessary with multiple users.  Then restart nginx!

Comment: I'm having the same error but I already added the proper `passenger_ruby` line to the nginx conf. I'm not sure what you mean by different users, can you explain a little bit on how did you fix it? In my case I'm getting the right folder for the ruby version with both commands.

Comment: The issue is with passenger-config.  That line is not necessary in `nginx/sites-enabled/yourApp`  if you have only one user on the server.  I cannot access that server anymore and cannot recall how this was dealt with with more than one user (sorry)